# Image block that produces simple "img" tag

Tags: html, wordpress

I thought this would be trivial, but it turns out that none of the block elements I found actually produce a simple `img` tag.

1. I intuitively tried the *Image* block element and it creates a `figure` tag around the `img`

   - also *Advanced Bootstrap Blocks* adds the Bootstrap classes to the `figure` element instead of the `img` element
   - manually editing the class attribute of the `img` tag get reverted when I change back to the visual editor
2. I inserted a media using the classic mode block and it surrounds the `img` with a `p` element

I just want a very simple block element that handles a single image and gives me the comfort of changing some options in the right hand menu (e.g. adding classes). In the end it should produce something like:

```html
<img src="..." class="..." alt="<pictures alt text>"/>
```

No extra stuff surrounding it.

Maybe there is an option I have overlooked or maybe someone can suggest a plugin that adds such a block element to WordPress (version 5.5.3).

My current solution is a *Custom HTML* block, but that obviously lacks all the comforts.

Comment: Most things will add more than just a plain image tag for SEO purposes, is there a reason you don't want a wrapping element?

Comment: @ZacharyCraig I can think of no SEO related reason to wrap an `img` tag into an extra `figure` or `p` element. Is there one?

Comment: I am using the *Advanced Bootstrap Blocks* plugin and want to add a Bootstrap card with an image (see [here](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/components/card/#images)). As I mentioned, using the *Image* block element does not apply the Bootstrap classes correctly, something the *Classic mode* plugin also struggles with.. my guess would be because of the extra `p` element, despite the fact that the *Classic mode* block element is a little dated. Also, adding unnecessary elements is still unnecessary.

Comment: If the `img` would be wrapped in a `div` I think I could live with that, but the `p` tag has its own styling.

Comment: Using the *Custom HTML* block is also not such a great solution because it does not apply the classes in the `class` attribute when previewing the output, i.e. the image.

Comment: How comfortable are you with PHP? Cause I would recommend creating your own custom block with Advanced Custom Fields

Comment: Or, you can modify the output of a core block with PHP or Javascript. Here is a good article on it: https://javascriptforwp.com/extending-wordpress-blocks/